# How to invoke an anchor with h:commandLink JSF

Tags: jsf

I want to replace a normal link that invoke an anchor < a href="#deleteModal" > with < h:commandLink > that invoke the same anchor. How to do that?

Thanks for your help.

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="locationTable"
    var="row"
    value="#{locationListBackingBean.list()}" 
    paginator="true" 
    rows="10"
    lazy="true"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,30,50"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">

    <p:column headerText="#">
        <h:outputText styleClass="id" style="" value="#{row.locationId}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Elminar">
        <a href="#deleteModal" id="remove" data-toggle="modal">
            <h:graphicImage styleClass="icon-remove" />
        </a>

        <!-- Dialog to confirm delete function. -->
        <div class="modal hide fade" id="deleteModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 id="deleteModalLabel">Eliminar</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Está seguro que desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h:commandButton styleClass="btn" value="Cancelar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"/>
            <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="Aceptar" action="#{locationListBackingBean.remove(row.locationId, row.recordVersion)}"/>
        </div>
        </div>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: I understand that your concrete functional requirement is that you'd like to be able to execute a backing bean action while maintaining the custom implemented jQuery UI specifics? Otherwise this question makes little sense. Well, this isn't possible without a custom renderer. As you're already using PrimeFaces, can't you better grab [`<p:confirmDialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf) instead of relying on custom implemented jQuery UI specifics?

Comment: I don't want to use < p:confirmDialog > because I want to use a botstrap confirm dialog. This is the principal reason for to do that.

Comment: Cleanest approach would be to create a custom JSF component+renderer for the Bootstrap confirm link and dialog (like as PrimeFaces did it for jQuery UI) so that it generates exactly the HTML you need and can be hooked on the JSF lifecycle. There is as far as I know no JSF component library based on Bootstrap.

Comment: How to do that? I'm beginner in the JSF world.